# vHost Configuration - Confluence - Errors

Tags: apache, confluence

### Summary:

I just spun up a digital ocean VM, put confluence on it, and set up the an apache vHost file for my subdomain. Now it appears that I am receiving errors when I am trying to edit pages and perform certain admin changes.

I believe that this is due to having no issue when visiting the server IP and port in Chrome:

### vHost file:

Source used: https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/using-apache-with-virtual-hosts-and-mod_proxy-173685.html

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.mydomain.com

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *:99999>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    ProxyPass / http://123.45.67.89:99999/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://123.45.67.89:99999/
    <Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Where:

- 123.45.67.89 is my Digital Ocean IP
- 99999 is a custom port number that is less than 65535

### Screenshots:

'Forbidden' from liking/unliking: `sub.mydomain.com`

[image]

Can Like/unlike : `http://123.45.67.89:99999`

[image]

Cannot update add-ons: `sub.mydomain.com`

[image]

Can update add-ons : `http://123.45.67.89:99999`

[image]

### Question:

Does anybody see what I am doing wrong?

**Thanks in advance for any help.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this was issue was easily solved by changing a setting confluence under general configuration:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/configuring-the-server-base-url-148592.html

> 1. Choose the cog icon, then choose General Configuration under Confluence Administration
> 2. Choose General Configuration in the left-hand panel
> 3. Choose Edit
> 4. Enter the new URL in the Server Base URL text box
> 5. Choose Save

If there is a better way to do this so I could have multiple domains work please let me know

I was thinking:

- notes.mydomain
- kb.mydomain
- grimoire.mydomain

^^ I have vHosts for all of these but I can only make edits on notes.mydomain ^^

I hope at the very least that this helps someone else.

**Thanks for reading!**